Не могу подключится к субд postgres
Всплывает ошибка:
utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 55: invalid continuation byte

Не понимаю вообще что это значит,
вроде бы не использовал какие-то особые символы.
Сама БД находится в локальной сети на линуксе.
import psycopg2
from config import host, user, password, db_name

connection = None
try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(
        host=host,
        user=user,
        password=password,
        database=db_name
    )

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT version()"
        )
        print(f"Server version: {cursor.fetchone()}")

except Exception as _ex:
    print(f"[DATABASE] Произошла ошибка при подлючении к бд {_ex}")
finally:
    if connection:
        connection.close()
        print("[DATABASE] Соединение с бд закрыто")


Проверьте версию библиотек. Убедитесь, что у вас установлена последняя версия библиотеки  psycopg2.

И добавьте полную трассировку ошибки в вопрос, пожалуйста!

Первое, проверьте кодировку БД через командную строку:
psql -h host -U user -d db_name -c "SELECT pg_encoding_to_char(encoding) FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'db_name';"

Второе, попробуйте задать кодировку при подключении:
connection = psycopg2.connect(
       host=host,
       user=user,
       password=password,
       database=db_name,
       options="-c client_encoding=utf8"
   )


а как мне проверить кодировку если я не могу подключится к бд, ну в самом бд у меня написано utf8

@Asdas Попробуйте использовать командную строку psql -h host -U user -d db_name -c "SELECT pg_encoding_to_char(encoding) FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'db_name';" Сейчас обновлю первый пункт. Второй пункт пробовали?
